# Boot Camp - running OS X partition as a VM

Tags: bootcamp, virtualization

Now while many users know that it is possible to run a Windows Boot Camp partition as a VM under OS X via VMWare or Parallels - however is the opposite possible? That is, in my case - I would like to know if I can boot into Windows 8.1 on my Retina MBP then access my OS X partition as a VM.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a legal impediment to run Mac OS X on Non-Apple hardware [sic!].
2. VMware Player & VMware Workstation therefore officially don't support the installation of Mac OS X on any hardware.
3. Breaking several EULAs you might install a patch to circumvent this restriction (I will not provide a link for the patches)
4. 

> Then with Workstation and a patch, you can boot into your OS X partition from Windows.
>
> But in order to access your macintosh HD partition first, you must create a blank OS X virtual machine.
>
> Note that Macintosh HD here means your OS X partition in your internal hard drive.
>   
>   [Source](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=18727104&postcount=6)

I didn't test this! So a full Time Machine backup and a full Boot Camp-partition backup deems advisable.

Comment: Being booted into Windows and then running Mac OS in a virtual machine like he described would not violate Apple's EULA - the underlying hardware still has the Apple logo on the back.